# How to select image in round shape from the iphone photo library

Tags: iphone

I am open iphone photo library from the my application.And i am selecting photo in squre shape.Its fine.But i want select photo in round shape.How it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clip it yourself:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/drawingwithquartz2d.pdf